# IntelliJ error when package name different than the folder name

Tags: intellij-idea

I was writing a simple class **HelloPrinter3.java**. It's in directory src/two. Now IntelliJ is giving me an **error**, saying *Package name 'three' does not correspond to the file path 'two'*. But it also compiles and runs fine.

[image]

I already know that a package name should not necessarily be the folder name. But what I am confused is the error. It cannot be the java error as the file would not have run. But then is it IntelliJ error? How can I differentiate between these two errors while writing code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This IDE inspection detects package statements that do not correspond to the project directory structure. Also, reports classes without package statements if the class is not located directly in source root directory.

While it's not strictly mandated by Java language, it's good to keep classes from package `com.example.myapp` inside the `com/example/myapp` directory under the source root. Failure to do this may confuse code readers and make some tools working incorrectly.

You can point the cursor at `package three` and press `Alt + Enter` to see which fixes the IDE suggest:

[image]

Also, you can disable this inspection in the IDE settings if needed:

[image]

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the clarification. And also for others, I also saw on the link [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) that this error is not an actual Java error but even before compiling, the IDE is checking our code. We can also change the severity level to show it as a warning or maybe not show it at all. But for the reasons @Egor has clarified above, I will keep this setting as it is.